# Is it possible to use different Vertex Array Objects with the same Shader Program?

Tags: opengl

I was going to render prisms and spheres, and both use the same shaders, only different buffers for their data (vertex positions and normals).

Is it possible to compile only one shader program and use a different VAO for each type of object?

Also, both of my object types use different attribute locations and the sphere uses an element array buffer as well, will it cause any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to compile only one shader program and use a different VAO for each type of object?

There is no direct link between the [shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) program object and the [vertex array object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).
When the draw call is performed, then the vertex attributes which are specified by the currently bound vertex array object are drawn, using the currently installed program.
So yes, you can use the same shader program, for drawing different set of vertices, referred by different vertex array objects.

> [...] both of my object types use different attribute locations [...]

The attribute index (location) is a active program resource and can't be changed after the shader program was linked.
The vertex attribute specification (stored  in the vertex array object) has to respect the active attribute indices of the program, but multiple vertex array objects can refer to the same vertex array buffer object(s).
It is possible to create different vertex array objects, which refer to (share) the same vertex buffer object(s), but associated them to different attribute locations. But note, the attribute locations of a shader program can't be changed.

> [...] the sphere uses an element array buffer as well, will it cause any problem?

Whether the index (element) buffer is used to draw the mesh, depends on the draw call ([`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) or [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml))